# RuntimeError: failed to factorize matrix

Tags: graph, scipy, pytorch, sparse-matrix, pytorch-geometric

I want to find the inversion of scipy.sparse.coo_matrix matrix.

> `adj = to_scipy_sparse_matrix(graph.edge_index)`
> <796022x796022 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float32'>'
> with 1791298 stored elements in COOrdinate format>

```
from scipy.sparse.linalg import inv
Dinv = inv(adj)
Dinv`
```

I write the above code but it show the error: RuntimeError: failed to factorize matrix

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
> 
> RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
> Input In \[77\], in \<cell line: 2\>()
> 1 from scipy.sparse.linalg import inv
> 2 Dinv = inv(adj2)
> 3 Dinv
> 
> File \~\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\scipy\\sparse\\linalg_matfuncs.py:75, in inv(A)
> 73 # Use sparse direct solver to solve "AX = I" accurately
> 74 I = \_ident_like(A)
> 75 Ainv = spsolve(A, I)
> 76 return Ainv
> 
> File \~\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\scipy\\sparse\\linalg_dsolve\\linsolve.py:236, in spsolve(A, b, permc_spec, use_umfpack)
> 233         x = x.ravel()
> 234 else:
> 235     # b is sparse
> 236     Afactsolve = factorized(A)
> 238     if not (isspmatrix_csc(b) or is_pydata_spmatrix(b)):
> 239         warn('spsolve is more efficient when sparse b '
> 240              'is in the CSC matrix format', SparseEfficiencyWarning)
> 
> File \~\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\scipy\\sparse\\linalg_dsolve\\linsolve.py:525, in factorized(A)
> 523     return solve
> 524 else:
> 525     return splu(A).solve
> 
> File \~\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\scipy\\sparse\\linalg_dsolve\\linsolve.py:366, in splu(A, permc_spec, diag_pivot_thresh, relax, panel_size, options)
> 363 if (\_options\["ColPerm"\] == "NATURAL"):
> 364     \_options\["SymmetricMode"\] = True
> 366 return \_superlu.gstrf(N, A.nnz, A.data, A.indices, A.indptr,
> 367                       csc_construct_func=csc_construct_func,
> 368                       ilu=False, options=\_options)
> 
> RuntimeError: failed to factorize matrix at line 110 in file ../../scipy/sparse/linalg/\_dsolve/SuperLU/SRC/ssnode_bmod.c
```

Comment: The warning suggests that `inv(adj.tocsc())` would be more efficient, though I suspect `inv`  is doing that conversion for you  (`sparse` code normally converts `coo` to `csr` or `csc` to do math).  But that may not make a difference.  The error occurs deep in compiled code,`ssnode_bmod.c`, so it's not available for further study.

Comment: It's a singular matrix. Can't invert a singular matrix.